# Auto complete plugin for squirrelmail removes display preferences page when enabled

Tags: ssh, squirrelmail

Running into a bit of a problem with Squirrelmail. I installed the Auto Complete plugin via SSH, and configured it using the conf.pl script. To my knowledge I did everything correctly, but there are two problems. 1. It doesn't work. 2. When the plugin is enabled the 'display preferences tab' under options disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out ...

For anyone else who might be having trouble this is all you have to do. Install the compatibility plugin found here.

http://squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=152